# is it possible to access findById at the same time in multiple collections with their separate file in a models folder

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Hello I have several collections in my mongoDB because I have several models and I wanted to display from findById the elements of the documents but it displays: req.next is not a function

```js
const getProductId = (req, res, next) => {

    User.findById(req.params.id, (error, product) => {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        console.log(product);
        res.render('product-detail', {
            product: product,
        })
    })
    Veste.findById(req.params.id, (error, product) => {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        console.log(product);
        res.render('product-detail', {
            product: product,
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Can we see where getProductId is called from?

Comment: getProductId  is called in a router folder:
module.exports = {getProductId: getProductId}

router.get('/product/:id', getIndexController.getProductId)

Comment: I don't see anything here that would try to call the `next` method of `req`.

Comment: yes it's true because it makes me req.next is not a function

Comment: there would be no other way to code this?

Comment: I don't think you can call render twice, but I also don't see where this reference to req.next is occurring.

Comment: If you are perfectly right to have made several it is not possible my problem I have several documents
and several files separate in my models folder and I can't access their ID

Comment: const User = require ("../ models / users")
const Jacket = require ("../ models / jacket")



I wanted to do that too but it doesn't work
 const getProductId = (req, res, next) => {
   const detail = [User, Jacket]
  detail.findById (req.params.id, (error, product) => {
   
    if (error) console.log (error);
    console.log (product);
    res.render ('product-detail', {
      product: product,
    })
    next ()
  })
}